# Is bumping your question for answers allowed?

Tags: support

Are you allowed to leave a "Bump" comment on your own question, if has not gotten an answer or has very few views?

Comment: It should be clarified that leaving comments in no way "bumps" a question on any SE site.  Edits are what "bump" questions, and edits specifically to move the question to the top of the front page are not welcome.

Answer (score 10):

No. Comments don't bump questions anyway. If you would like more exposure for your question, the best thing to do is set a bounty.

Comment: i just tried it and it seemed to bump my question to the to the top again.

Comment: but if its not allowed, it doesn't really matter :)

Comment: @RustyMembers In general, comments that don't add to the post are not welcome. Comments bumping the post would definitely fall into this category and likely be removed.

Comment: @RustyMembers The comment didn't boost the question up, the super minor edit did.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the Community user will automagically bump old posts with no positively scored answers, if a post goes for a while without an answer.

Comment: oh okay thanks.